# concat char in sysout gives weird output?

Tags: java, char, concatenation

When I run the following code it doesn't give me the output that I've been excepted. Consider the following code-snippet:

```
public class T
{
    public static void main(String arg[])
    {
        char a='3';
        System.out.println(a+a);
    }
}
```

The output here is : 102

Could please anybody explain that to me ?

Comment: You should have a look at the specs for [15.18. Additive Operators](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.18) and btw be aware that chars are actually 16-bit unsigned integers representing UTF-16 (with the range of 000000 - 00007F matching ascii).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `+` operator applies an implicit type cast which converts the two characters into their numerical ASCII representation which is 51.

So the expression

```
'3'+'3'
```

can also be seen as

```
51 + 51
```

which is 102.

I assume what you want to have is the result `"33"` which is not a char any more but a string. To achieve this you can for example simply implicitly convert the result of the expression into a string:

```
char c = '3';
string s = "" + c + c;
```

Another possibility would be to facilitate the StringBuilder class:

```
char c = '3';
String s = new StringBuilder().append(c).append(c).toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

a+a is interpreted as a formula.

since ascii value of '3' is 51, 51 + 51 = 102.

Answer (score 0):

It is just the sum of ascii values

Answer (score 0):

you can see c+c as 51 + 51, because it takes the ascii code of '3'.
if you want to print 33, then you can try this:

```
System.out.println(String
```

.format("%c + %c", c, c));